# Scale a div (keeping its aspect ratio) given its parent's width and height using css

Tags: css

I have been searching for how to create the aspect ratio of divs using the CSS stylesheet; I could successfully create a demo. The aspect ratio works fine but I can not find a way to set the height of my container if its width and height ratio is bigger (#1 scenario).

[image]

I managed to successfully create the #2 scenario. But when I try to create #1 scenario, the container's height expands, here is my code:

```css
HTML, body {
 margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
    
#container{
 background: khaki;
    padding: 10px;
 display: table;
 width: 150px;
 height: 300px;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#container:hover {
    width: 500px; /* Only increasing the width */
   height: 300px;
}

#c-ver-al {
 background: lightblue;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: -webkit-center;
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 height 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#c-hor-al {
 background: pink;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: -webkit-center;
 display: inline-block;
 object-fit: cover;
 height 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#frame {
 padding: 10px;
 background: lightgray;
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#window {
 width: 66%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
 background: blue;
}

#chat {
 width: 33%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
 background: red;
}

.content {
 display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  if you hover over it, only the container's width will be increased, not the height
   <div id="container">
      <div id="c-ver-al">
        <div id="c-hor-al">
          <div id="frame">
            <div id="chat" class="content"></div>  
            <div id="window" class="content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    The height of the container should not change, but it is 
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I've only added padding to the divs so it would be easier to visualize where they currently are. Also, ignore my poorly made demo, I am a beginner in HTML and in CSS and I might have missed something very obvious.

Edit: I have made a hover action on css so you can see the aspect ratio working

Comment: @media might be a solution but I have never used it before

Comment: Did you find the solution for scaling the div in parent with given width and height?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your two inner elements' `padding-bottom`. Because of **[the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)**, when you apply a percentage-based `padding` to an element, it **[calculates based off of the parents (bubbling) `width`](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/)****, ignoring the **`height`**.

To resolve this, simply set a fixed `padding-bottom`:

```css
HTML,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  background: khaki;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px; /* Increased for demo */
  height: 150px; /* To fit within snippet */
  display: table;
}

#c-ver-al {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#c-hor-al {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
  height 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#frame {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#window {
  width: 66%;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  background: blue;
}

#chat {
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="c-ver-al">
      <div id="c-hor-al">
        <div id="frame">
          <div id="chat" class="content"></div>
          <div id="window" class="content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to have the child actually **exceed** the parent container, then you'll want to use negative `margin`.

Comment: This does fix the #1 scenario but It breaks the relative ratio demo, If you increase the width of the container by a large number, like 1000, the gray/white box does not keep the same shape as previously, maybe if we add a calc() somewhere